# Strange behavior with jQuery toggleClass. Alert will work but not the toggle

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have three different checkboxes. I know that I should just have one click function with the tree different classes but I'm just breaking it down here to show you (I tried the one click to 3 classes and was getting the same behavior.

Tried this initially and only `.override` works:

```
$(".override, paaudiooverride, .pavideooverride").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('override-checked');
});
```

Decided to break them into 3 (only for now/to get it working) and still only `.override` is working:

```
//this one works
$(".override").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('override-checked');
});
//but this one doesnt
$(".pavideooverride").click(function(){
    //$(this).toggleClass('override-checked');
    alert("checked");
});
//and neither does this one
$(".paaudiooverride").click(function(){
    //$(this).toggleClass('override-checked');
    alert("audio checked");
});
```

Why in the world is that the alerts are recognized but the `toggleClass` is not?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e8L9E/1/

Comment: Right right. So very strange as the alert works in my code but not the toggleClass. Hm...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, figured it out. It was the placement of `override-checked` within the CSS file. It was AFTER the `override` class but BEFORE the audio and video override classes. So I moved the `override-checked` class to the bottom of the CSS file and all is working well.